# select values from a table where column values should be different

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

Let us say there are 4 columns in a table .

```
cpt,cpt4mod,itemcharge,eff_date.
```

condition1: if the values of `cpt,cpt4` and `itemcharge` are same, but `eff_date` is different. Then I need to fetch the latest record based on `eff_date`.

condtition2: if the values of `cpt` and `cpt4` are same, but `eff_date` and `itemcharge` are different. Then I need to fetch the latest record based on `eff_date`.

condtition3:if all columns have the same values, then I need to fetch the latest record based on `eff_date`

condtition4: if the values of `cpt,cpt4and,eff_date` are same  but`itemcharge`  is different. Then I need to fetch all the records except the latest one

Comment: The question's wording seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Well, condition2 seems to cover condition1 and condition3 too. What you probably need would be something like:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            N = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cpt, cpt4 ORDER BY eff_date DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N = 1;
```

This should cover everyone of your conditions.

Comment: Except condition 4, which requires several rows are returned?

Comment: @MaxVernon yes, that's why I used `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`, since they should all have the value `N = 1`. Though I just noticed the "except the latest one" requirement in that condition, which I have to say I have no idea what it means, because the value for `eff_date` is supposed to be the same

Comment: yeah.  Agreed.  it's a pretty poorly worded question.